# wpf - bind polyline to custom class

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Does anyone know whether it is possible to bind a polyline to a collection of custom objects?

For example, I have a class like so:

```
public class MyDataClass{
    public double Value { get; set; } //I'd like to map this to a polyline point's x value
    public double Position { get; set; } //I'd like to map this to a polyline point's y value
}
```

And I'd like to bind a polyline to a collection of those objects and translate the Value property to X and the Position property to Y.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Polyline` is expecting a `PointCollection` of `Points` in order to draw them, you could use a converter to assure that :
Xaml

```
<Polyline Stretch="Fill" Grid.Column="0"
      Name="Polyline" Stroke="Red"
      Points="{Binding Points,Converter={StaticResource ToPointConverter}}">
    </Polyline>
```

the converter is implemented like so:

```
public class ToPointConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;            
        var pointCollection=new PointCollection();
        (value as List<MyDataClass>).ForEach(x=>{pointCollection.Add(new Point()
        {
            X = x.Value,
            Y = x.Position
        });});
        return pointCollection;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and in your codebehind or your Viewmodel define the `List<MyDataClass>` property :

```
public List<MyDataClass> Points { get; set; }
```

don't forget to set the `DataContext` and set the `ToPointConverter` in your resource.

`

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I didn't realise that I could use a converter on the whole collection.

Answer (score 1):

Although already answered by Joseph, I'd like to add a shorter and more flexible implementation of the Convert method, which uses the [LINQ Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) method:

```
using System.Linq;
...

public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var myDataCollection = value as IEnumerable<MyDataClass>;

    if (myDataCollection == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return new PointCollection(
        myDataCollection.Select(p => new Point(p.Value, p.Position)));
}
```